# Set value of Input value based on dropdown selection in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I have a dropdown with few values and based on the value selected, the input field value should be set.

Here is my html code

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    Services
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="bgrp" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Services</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <nb-select selected="1" fullWidth id="service" (change)=onChange($event)>
                <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [value]="service">{{service.name}}</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="bgrp" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Unit Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="number" nbInput fullWidth id="name" name="price"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="bgrp" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Discount</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="number" nbInput fullWidth id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

And my typescript file is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-service',
  templateUrl: './service.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  Services: any=[
    {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
    {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
    {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
    {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
    {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public onChange(event){
    const val = event.target.value;
    this.price.setValue(event.target.value,{
      onlySelf: true
    })
  }


}
```

So if consultation is selected, price should be set to 100.
if x ray is selected, price should be set to 500.

I want it using reactiveformmodule methods
Help me out...

Comment: What research have you done so far on reactive forms? What have you tried so far to get it working? What's your specific problem?

Comment: I didn't do much research on reactive forms. I'm just a beginner. I searched online how to do it, but didn't work for me. few of them used ngModel, but those didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I got answer to my question, I have done some changes to my code.

In HTML

```
<nb-select type="number" fullWidth id="service" [(ngModel)]="price" (ngModelchange)="toPrice()" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [value]="service.price">{{service.name}}</nb-option>

 <input type="number" nbInput fullWidth id="name" name="price" value="{{price}}"/>
```

and in .ts File

```
price:number;
  Services: Array<object>=[
    {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
    {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
    {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
    {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
    {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];

toPrice(){
    this.price =+ this.price
    console.log(this.price);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it without testing your code,
I suggest you to use (change)=yourfunction() for that. It's what you did but you forget to use ngModel to bindings your value then hang it with your function.

Comment: Can you please tell me more

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this solution**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <nb-select selected="1" fullWidth id="service" (change)=onChange($event)>
        <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [value]="service.price">{{service.name}}</nb-option>
     </nb-select>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. You didn't mention any reference to the input field. How its value gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Hello just declare a variable selectedService in your .ts file and initialize it in ngOnInit function.This variable will hold the selected Service.This the whole ts file.

```
  selectedService: any;
   Services: any=[
    {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
    {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
    {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
    {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
    {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];
ngOnInit() {
this.selectedService = new Object();
  }
```

Then in your HTML file you have to connect them with the same NgModel, this is an example of my HTML file:

```
<label>Service</label>
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedService">
    <option *ngFor="let service of Services" [ngValue]="service">
      {{service.name}}</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="selectedService.price" >
```

Comment: ERROR Error: "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions. Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">"              

I was getting this error

Comment: check the edited answer without any errors.I guess this is the proper way of impletenting what you want.